# I need to order alphabetically a database select query in flutter

Tags: android, sqlite, flutter

the following is the flutter code, does anybody got a recomendation on how to do it?

```
 Future getAllProducts() async {
    final db = await database;
    final res = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tableProduct");
    return res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((c) => Product.fromJson(c)).toList() : [];
  }
```

Comment: See [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) for help about SQL Order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**

Modify query like

```
"SELECT * FROM $tableProduct ORDER BY yourColumnName"
```

**OR**

After return or before returns do

```
YourListVariable.sort((a, b) {
  return a['columnName'].toLowerCase().compareTo(b['ColumnName'].toLowerCase());
});
```